# Oracle Procedure: Creating dynamic WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

I am creating a dynamic where clause, but its' reporting `Error(40,51): PL/SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword` at `column_2 in ('x','y','z')`, the error remains for other operators as well.

```
select *
from test_table
where column_1 = <Some_value>
  and (case column_2
          when 'A' then
            column_2 in ('x','y','z')
            column_3 in (1, 2)
          when 'B' then
            column_2 in ('p', 'q', 'r')
            column_3 in (2, 3)
          else
            column_2 = 'x'
            column_3 = 1
        end case);
```

Also I need to add a where condition is passed in parameters in not null, something like this

```
where column_1 = <Some_value>
 if (param_value <> null) then
      column_2 = param_value
end if
```

Please suggest how can I achieve the desire.

Comment: What you try to write does not seem to be Oracle SQL syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can't dynamically "attach" IN clauses like that, but there are a few different ways to do this:

```
where column_1 = <Some_value>
  and (
     (column_2 = 'A' AND
      column_2 in ('x','y','z') AND
      column_3 in (1, 2)) 
  OR (column_2 = 'B' AND
      column_2 in ('p', 'q', 'r') AND
      column_3 in (2, 3))
  OR (column_2 NOT IN ('A','B') AND
      column_2 = 'x'
      column_3 = 1)
      )
```

or

```
where column_1 = <Some_value>
  and (case column_2
          when 'A' then
            (column_2 = 'x' OR column_2 = 'y' OR column_2 = 'z')
            AND
            (column_3 = 1 OR  column_3 = 2)
          when 'B' then
            (column_2 = 'p' OR column_2 = 'q' OR column_2 = 'r')
            AND
            (column_3 = 2 OR  column_3 = 3)
          else
            column_2 = 'x'
            AND
            column_3 = 1
        end case);
```

or do a seaparate query for each CASE condition and UNION them.

Comment: `AND ((COUNTRY_CODE IS NOT NULL) AND
(country.CODE = COUNTRY_CODE))`
This works fine if I pass valid COUNTRY_CODE but filters out all records for `null` COUNTRY_CODE. Please suggest right way to do that.

Comment: I would post that as a separate question and provide more code and context - what do you _want_ to happen?